# Android adding an image to an app for later use

Tags: android, android-studio

My project (in AndroidStudio) would need an image that will be loaded later for processing. This is going to be a noob question I know...

I have the image file on my computer (myimage.bmp), and I need to add it to my project, so that when I test my app on the device, the image file will be loaded into the device and I could access it from code.

What do I do?
Where do I put the file and how do I access it's path?

So far I tried placing it inside the `drawable` folder, I even created a new folder named `raw` and placed it there, but I cannot seem to locate it from my app.

To locate it I try this code:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(path,"myimage.bmp");
```

I also tried:

```
File file = new File(path,"/myProjectName/myimage.bmp");
```

still nothing.
Also I launched the file navigator on my device, went to `storage/sdcard0/` that is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` and I looked for a folder named like my project but there isn't any folder called like that.

It is obvious I am doing something wrong, and I am out of ideas on how to search for what I want on google, so please be so kind and tell me: in what folder do I have to place my image inside the project, and how do I get it so I can assign it to a File?

**EDIT**

This is my code to check for the file:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(path,"/MyProjectName/myimage.bmp"); 
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.e("FILE Stuff:",path + "/MyProjectName/myimage.bmp");
            Log.e("FILE Stuff:","File exists");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("FILE Stuff:",path + "/MyProjectName/myimage.bmp");
            Log.e("FILE Stuff:","File does not exist");
        }
       Bitmap objectbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + "/MyProjectName/myimage.bmp");
```

And as I mentioned, the file isn't there... even if I placed the file inside `C:\MyAndroidTests\MyProject\app\src\res\raw\` folder

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should add you files to /res/raw folder. And then use a resource id (R.raw.xxx) to get this file and copy it to external storage.
For instance, I have a sqlite table and want to copy it from my APP to external storage when first time launch this APP.
So,

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.table);

            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            os.flush();
            os.close();
            is.close();
```

This will do. DB_PATH & DB_NAME are two strings for database path and database file name.
Don't forget to wrap those code in a try...catch.

Comment: So I still cant find it. So I moved the raw folder inside the res folder, and placed the image inside it. But: in the filenavigator of the device there still isn't any folder with the name of my project, and the opening of the file still does not work, because the file isn't where it is supposed to be. Check my EDIT in the question for some more code

Comment: Here is the thing, for each APP in Android, the operating system will allocate a default folder named using your package name in "/data/data". This folder is in internal storage. Only your APP can add/edit/delete file in this folder. I think what you are trying is first copy a image file in your APP package(*.apk) to external storage(like a sdcard), then read or display this image.

Comment: What you need to do is, first check your sdcard is exist or not. Then create folders in it, like "myappImages/". Then you should use the code I provide or something like that to copy your image file from /res/raw/ to /sdcard/myappImages/.

Comment: BTW, The file navigator APP only show the content in your sdcard.

Comment: So if I do not use sdcard, but internal storage... then I do not need to create folders manually and saving resources there... I assume. If that is so, then how do I access the file? Like I said, I can add the file in /res/raw/ folder. How can I access it to open the file like in the question?

Comment: Use the code in the answer. Change the file name to "myPic.bmp" and use it to create File. `File myPicFile = new File("myPic.bmp");` Then create the file use `myPicFile.createNewFile();`  After that use this file to create a OutputStream and do the copy work. This myPic.bmp will be created in folder "/data/data/your.package.name/". You don't need to use the absolute file path.

Comment: And if you only want to display this image, there is no need to copy it to disk at all. Just use `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xxx)` . This will return a drawable resource and you can place it in a ImageView what so ever. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting your image in assets folder and access it in this manner

```
File file = new File(file:///android_asset/image1.png);
```

**Edit:**
Get the path of the image from drawable folder

```
 Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://{your_app_package_name}/drawable/icon");

    String path = path.toString();
 File file = new File(path);
```

Comment: There is no assets folder in my structure. Also I really need to access it like in the code above. Can you elaborate?

Comment: create assets folder in your project and move image in it and try using in the manner as mentioned in the answer

Comment: If I add Image asset to the project, it tries to make 4 versions of my image in order to place them in the drawable folders for each resolution. I do not want to do that. I just need a picture to be added to my project and that I can access it from code. Asset can only be "Launcher icons", "ActionBar and Tab icons" or "Notification icons". I do not want to complicate my life and app and code like this. There must be a simple - direct way to access a file from storage

Comment: Please test your code and come back to me. It's not working. Also it's not correct... First, it should be `String path = otherPath.toString();` then in the Uri I should specify the fileName somewhere right?